# How to get the most frequent value in Google's Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

Postgres has an easy function to achieve this, just using the [mode()](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Aggregate_Mode) function we can find the most frequent value. Is there something equivalent within Google's Bigquery?

How could be written a query like this in Bigquery?

```
select count(*),
       avg(vehicles)                                         as mean,
       percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by vehicles) as median,
       mode() within group (order by vehicles)               as most_frequent_value
FROM "driver"
WHERE vehicles is not null;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

Option 1

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt,
    AVG(vehicles) AS mean,
    APPROX_TOP_COUNT(vehicles, 1)[OFFSET(0)].value AS most_frequent_value
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  WHERE vehicles IS NOT NULL
) CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT PERCENTILE_CONT(vehicles, 0.5) OVER() AS median
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  WHERE vehicles IS NOT NULL
  LIMIT 1
)
```

Option 2

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(*) cnt,
    AVG(vehicles) AS mean
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  WHERE vehicles IS NOT NULL
) CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT PERCENTILE_CONT(vehicles, 0.5) OVER() AS median
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  WHERE vehicles IS NOT NULL
  LIMIT 1
) CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT vehicles AS most_frequent_value
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  WHERE vehicles IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY vehicles
  ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC
  LIMIT 1
)
```

Option 3

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION median(arr ANY TYPE) AS ((
  SELECT PERCENTILE_CONT(x, 0.5) OVER() 
  FROM UNNEST(arr) x LIMIT 1 
));
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION most_frequent_value(arr ANY TYPE) AS ((
  SELECT x 
  FROM UNNEST(arr) x
  GROUP BY x
  ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC
  LIMIT 1  
));
SELECT COUNT(*) cnt,
  AVG(vehicles) AS mean,
  median(ARRAY_AGG(vehicles)) AS median,
  most_frequent_value(ARRAY_AGG(vehicles)) AS most_frequent_value
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WHERE vehicles IS NOT NULL
```

and so on ...

Comment: Note that option 3 does not work well if there are NULL values. In that case, you can set the NULL values to e.g. 'unknown' so you don't get an empty ARRAY, and add to the `TEMP FUNCTION most_frequent_value`: `WHERE x != 'unknown'`

Answer (score 10):

You can use `APPROX_TOP_COUNT` to get top values, e.g.:

```
SELECT APPROX_TOP_COUNT(vehicles, 5) AS top_five_vehicles
FROM dataset.driver
```

If you just want the top value, you can select it from the array:

```
SELECT APPROX_TOP_COUNT(vehicles, 1)[OFFSET(0)] AS most_frequent_value
FROM dataset.driver
```

Comment: If you just want the value, append `.value` - the function returns a struct with value and count.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no equivalent of the `mode()`-function in BigQuery, but you may **define one yourself** using any of the logics in the other answers to this thread. You could call it like so:

```sql
SELECT mode(`an_array`) AS top_count FROM `somewhere_with_arrays`
```

but this approach lead to multiple by-row sub-queries wihch is terrible for performance, so if you never grinded BQ to a halt before, you can do it with these functions. I it (the second) only for readability in quick-fixes for very small data-sets.

Check out the two UDF:s below. A third approach would be to implement a JS function in which case this oneliner should be usefull

```js
return arr.sort((a,b) => arr.filter(v => v===a).length - arr.filter(v => v===b).length).pop();
```

**This code establishes two `mode()`-like functions which eat arrays and return most common string:**

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION mode1(mystring ANY TYPE)
RETURNS STRING
AS
(
    (
        SELECT var FROM
        (   /* Count occurances of each value of input */ 
            SELECT var, COUNT(*) AS n FROM 
                (   /* Unnest and name*/
                    SELECT var FROM UNNEST(mystring) var
                )
                GROUP BY var    /* Output is one of existing values */
                ORDER BY n DESC /* Output is value with HIGHEST n   */
        )                       /* -------------------------------- */
    LIMIT 1                     /* Only ONE string is the output    */
    )
);

CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION mode2(inp ANY TYPE)
RETURNS STRING
AS
(
    (
        SELECT result.value FROM UNNEST( (SELECT APPROX_TOP_COUNT(v,1) AS result FROM UNNEST(inp) v)) result
    )
);

SELECT
    inp,
    mode1(inp) AS first_logic_output,
    mode2(inp) AS second_logic_output
FROM
(
    /* Test data */
    SELECT ['Erdős','Turán', 'Erdős','Turán','Euler','Erdős'] AS inp
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT ['Euler','Euler', 'Gauss', 'Euler'] AS inp
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The method I prefer is to query off of an array since you can easily adjust the criteria of the mode. Below are two example using both an offset and a limit method. With the offset you can grab the Nth most/least frequent value.

```
WITH t AS (SELECT 18 AS length, 
'HIGH' as amps, 
99.95 price UNION ALL
SELECT 18,  "HIGH", 99.95 UNION ALL
SELECT 18,  "HIGH", 5.95 UNION ALL
SELECT 18,  "LOW", 33.95 UNION ALL
SELECT 18,  "LOW", 33.95 UNION ALL
SELECT 18,  "LOW", 4.5 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,  "HIGH", 77.95 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,  "HIGH", 77.95 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,  "HIGH", 9.99 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,  "LOW", 44.95 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,  "LOW", 44.95 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,  "LOW", 5.65 
)

SELECT
length,
amps,

-- By Limit
(SELECT x FROM UNNEST(price_array) x 
    GROUP BY x ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1 ) most_freq_price,
(SELECT x FROM UNNEST(price_array) x 
    GROUP BY x ORDER BY COUNT(*) ASC  LIMIT 1 ) least_freq_price,

-- By Offset
ARRAY((SELECT x FROM UNNEST(price_array) x 
    GROUP BY x ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC))[OFFSET(0)] most_freq_price_offset,
ARRAY((SELECT x FROM UNNEST(price_array) x 
    GROUP BY x ORDER BY COUNT(*) ASC))[OFFSET(0)] least_freq_price_offset

FROM (
SELECT 
    length,
    amps,
    ARRAY_AGG(price) price_array
FROM t
GROUP BY 1,2
)
```